# Matlab and cvNamedWindow of OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm working with `OpenCV` programs in `C++` and calling them in `Matlab` using `calllib`.

The thing is that when the program exits the `cvNamedWindows` does not close.

I've tried `DestroyWindow` and `DestroyAllWindows`  but inside `Matlab` it won't close.

Here is some code

```
int main()
{
  int device = 0;
  vCap = VideoCapture( device );

  Mat img;
  vCap >> img;

  imshow("colour", img);
  cv::waitKey(1);

  namedWindow("colour",1);
  cv::destroyWindow("colour");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C++ code. I don't understand what you are trying to do with this and `calllib`. If you want to use opencv in Matlab, have a look to this [mexfile](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv)

Comment: The thing is using `calllib` I can use pointers.

Comment: Maybe you can look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842901/opencv-closing-the-image-display-window)

Comment: `cvStartWindowThread();` works if I have only one named window opened.

Comment: If you create multiple window, did you use `destroyWindow(Name)`? or `destroyAll()` ?

Comment: turns out it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post @AlexandreBizeau posted in comments has the answer,

```
cvStartWindowThread();
```