# Python freezes after cv2.destroyWindow()

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

I am using openCV under Python 2.7 on Mac OS X (Lion)...Whenever I run code to simply display a camera feed (from iSight) Python freezes. It looks like the camera is not actually getting cleaned up. I have used a number of different versions of the same code (below, which is from a different question on SO) and get the same results (whether in cv or cv2). Anyone have any idea why this is happening? Here is the code:

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("camera",1)
capture = cv2.VideoCapture()
capture.open(0)
while True:
    img = capture.read()[1]
    cv2.imshow("camera", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27: break
cv2.destroyWindow("camera")
```

Comment: It might be a bug in the library. Have you tried to call `capture.release()` explicitly?

Comment: Hm. I just tried adding `capture.release()` before `cv2.destroyWindow("camera")` and, while it does clean up the camera (the iSight light now goes off), Python still freezes.

Comment: So problem seems to be in the `destroyWindow` itself. Does it freezes if you remove the `destroyWindow` call (window should be closed automatically when script ends) or replace it with `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`?

Comment: Yeah, sounds that way. Tried removing `cv2.destroyWindow("camera")` (so the script ends with `capture.release()`) and it still freezes. Then tried replacing `cv2.destroyWindow("camera") with `destroyAllWindows()` and also freezes. I would be happy to send a bug report on this issue and report back if you have any idea who i contact regarding such a thing.

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem with all *nux based system. Please check out this question and the answer from other question on StackOverflow.

[DestroyWindow does not close window on Mac using Python and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116564/destroywindow-does-not-close-window-on-mac-using-python-and-opencv)

In short, it seems that you will need to call waitKey() for the message pump in OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same the problem and this is my solution.

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

and after loop put this

```
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

PD: in this line of code capture = cv2.VideoCapture() your should define one value of the camera.

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this alternate method,
**IT REQUIRES ANACONDA ENVIRONMENT**
My suggestion is to run code in python in terminal. You will not face any kind of problem

Copy the same code and save with filename.py

```
import cv2
input = cv2.imread('path_to_image.png')
cv2.imshow('Hello World', input)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

then open specific directory and then open terminal

Open terminal - `cd path/to/filename.py`

- source activate YOURPROFILE
- python filename.py

This will solve problem

https://youtu.be/8O-FW4Wm10s

Answer (score 0):

Which IDE are you using? I was facing the same problem when I was using the `default IDE` (IDLE) but, then I installed `PyCharm`, it works perfectly now, the image window closes instantly, also use `waitkey(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Put cv2.destroyAllWindows before break. It will surely work.

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        stream.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cv2.waitKey(1)`
after `cv2.destroyWindow("img_name")` or `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`. So it would look like this:

```
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

P.S.: I am using **MacOS Monterey** and it worked. I read it from [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/102328/destroywindow-and-destroyallwindows-not-working/).

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works for me even in default IDE:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    stream.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    break
```