# imshow freezes when closing down in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to detect three types of fruit using a model and opencv for the webcam. Everything works, but when i try to close it down it freezes and i have to use task manager to close it down.
This is the code I'm using:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True: 
    ret,img=cap.read()
    cv2.startWindowThread()
    cv2.imshow('Video', img)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))
    pred = what_fruit(img)
    print(pred)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
            break
```

Is there a way to use opencv webcam and have it close down correctly in notebook?

Comment: I suggest this read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882255/is-it-possible-to-display-an-opencv-video-inside-the-ipython-jupyter-notebook and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734276/python-freezes-after-cv2-destroywindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you forgot two lines of code after the while loop:

```
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```