# OpenCV -> Python - image window does not close

Tags: python, opencv, user-input, raw-input

I need the user input after showing an image, but the problem is that the image window will not close and will freeze. Do you have some solution or alternative that I can use to get the user input?

**Code:**

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("begin.jpg")
cv2.imshow("test",img)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
raw_input("test:")
```

**Problem:** Window that show image will not close

**Cause:** raw_input(). Removing the raw_input() the window closes as expected.

**I expect more than one character from the user.**

Thank you so much

Comment: If your code ran as expected it would actually show and hide the window immediately. Anyway, `waitKey` is the likely the function you want to use here. It forces a refresh of the window either immediately, after a timeout, or after a key press.

Comment: Yes, if the code ran as expected the window would show and hide immediately. What I do not understand is why the raw_input makes the destroyAllWindows does not work... About waitKey, my problem is not that the window will show and hide immediately, I put the code like this to show that the raw_input, does not let the window to close. With waitKey one can also read a char, but I would like to receive more than one...

Comment: Don't use `waitKey` as the user input, except for them to close the window. Then collect their input with `raw_input`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want...but the problem is that the window does not close.

Comment: Put another `waitKey` after the destroy window command?

Comment: That was the solution that I did before posting, but thank you for the idea ;) I am intrigued with this behavior of destroy_window and raw_input...I also tried to run in a separate thread the code for opening and close the window, but even after the end of the thread, the window does not close if there is a raw_input following the end of the thread...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116564/destroywindow-does-not-close-window-on-mac-using-python-and-opencv

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: I found the next info in openCV DevZone, it looks like a bug: http://code.opencv.org/issues/2911 it works for me.