# cv2.destroyWindow() does not work as expected

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi

I just started to learn OpenCV with Python for Raspberry Pi 3.
I wrote a simple code for namedWindow(). The problem is destroyWindow() does not work as I expect. The "TEST" window is still there. What is wrong with the following code?

```
import cv2
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cv2.namedWindow("TEST")
    while True:
        key = cv2.waitKey(5)
        if key == 27:
            print "ESC pressed..."
            cv2.destroyWindow("TEST")
            break
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: You may want to check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116564/destroywindow-does-not-close-window-on-mac-using-python-and-opencv).

Comment: move the destroyWindow("TEST") out of the loop.

Comment: When I was last working with `destroyWindow`, I had to not only put a few different calls of `waitKey` before and after the `destroyWindow` (two in front, five after), I also had to start a `cvWindowThread` right before I created the `namedWindow`. Then I called `std::terminate()` at then end, as the thread wasn't closing properly (mind, that was in C++, python might handle the threads better).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what usually works for me as far as the waitKey goes:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
    break
cv2.destroyWindow("TEST")
```

Which is a bitwise and with the waitkey input and `11111111` which should equal the UTF-8 value for the key. I tested this on [This Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374138/cv2-gettrackbarpos-not-working/). Hope this helps.