# python opencv: destroyallwindow does not work

Tags: python, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, opencv

I am a beginner in image processing, opencv, and python.
I want to display an image using jupyter notebook on Mac and close the window but its not working.  In addition, python.app stops working so I have to force quit it, causing my kernel to die, which I then have to restart as well.
I am using python 2.7 for this and opencv 3.4.1

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

it is partially not duplicate as it tries to seek answer for jupyter notebook.

Comment: My suggestion is to run code in python in terminal. You will not face any kind of problem

Comment: Try to run `cv2.startWindowThread()` before `img = cv2.[...]`

Comment: Or, maybe, in between `img = cv2.[...]` and `cv2.imshow[...]`

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116564/destroywind..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116564/destroywindow-does-not-close-window-on-mac-using-python-and-opencv#15058451) it is outdated now. it would be helpful if you update it please

Comment: thats what I pointed out in my last comment.... I have seen it but it is 7 years old and code is not working.
p.s. I can also see the LINKED category on my RHS

Comment: @ankiiiiiii try using `cv2.waitKey(1)` at the end.

Comment: @JeruLuke `cv2.waitKey(1)` has no effect in jupyter and in terminal it works without that too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe its the copy of the mentioned question but I followed the first comment and got it solved by using terminal but someone need to find and tell why jupyter causes such problem.

Comment: This was provided as a suggestion in the question asked 7 years ago as well !!!

Comment: in the last answer, It still hangs as an issue. it would be great if someone really fixes it seeing either mine or his/her question.
sorry if I sounded rude..

Comment: It's ok. Just trying to help :)