# Why cv2.destroyAllWindows() does not work on mac?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to learn OpenCV framework on python3 and when I want to destroy an opened image, nothing happens and the only way to close the window is "Force Quit". I tried some solutions like‍ `cv2.startWindowThread()` but it didn't work for me. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
cv2.startWindowThread()
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

versions:

python -> 3.6.0

OpenCV -> 3.3.0

macOS High Sierra -> 10.13.6

---

Update:

I was trying to run the code in jupyter-notebook and when I tried to run it in Pycharm I had no more problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DestroyWindow does not close window on Mac using Python and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116564/destroywindow-does-not-close-window-on-mac-using-python-and-opencv)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why by for me the following work-around works:

```
cv2.imshow(name, img)
cv2.startWindowThread()
print(cv2.waitKey(0))
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
for i in range(2):
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25794701/3650983) answer